# Adding JPanel after pressing key

Tags: java

I want to add a panel to my Container `pane` after pressing a key. I first thought it would be easier to simply make it visible under the key pressing:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setSize(400, 400);
pane.add("South",panel);
JTextField userText = new JTextField(72);
panel.add(userText);
panel.setVisible(false);  


@Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        };

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


    };
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
if (e.getKeyChar() == ':') {
    //JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       panel.setVisible(true);  
    }

};
```

I also added the `addKeyListener(this);` clause to the class constructor.

Is there a way to "pass" the panel and/or the pane to the keyPressed(KeyEvent e) ? That is the error I get.

Comment: your code is not complete here, so cannot be tested, nor analyzed for typos.

Comment: Can you specify what error you get? The stacktrace maybe?

Comment: can you share code in detail.

Comment: I get "error: cannot find symbol
     panel.setVisible(true);"